# Creating new instance of existing page to add to UIScrollView (paging)

Tags: objective-c

In part of my app, a button click creates a new page. However, I want that page to be exactly the same as the one I was on previously, but just a new instance of it. After asking the best way to do this on SO, I learned the UIScrollView with paging enabled was the best approach. So, I wrote some code to try to do what I was trying. However, when I press the button, the app just crashes. I'm assuming it got into some kind of recursion (calling itself again and again). Any insight into what might be wrong would be great. I can confirm that all the outlets are hooked up to their respective positions in StoryBoard.

```
-(IBAction)createContainer:(id)sender {


    [allScrollViews addObject:self.containerView];
    for (int i = 0; i < allScrollViews.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.containerView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.containerView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = self.view;
        subview.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;
        [self.containerView addSubview:subview];

    }

    self.containerView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.containerView.frame.size.width * allScrollViews.count, self.containerView.frame.size.height);   

}
```

Once again, pressing the button has to pretty much duplicate the view that I'm on (ViewController.m), and just make a new instance of it on a new page. My code is hopefully close to what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks much!
~Carpetfizz

EDIT: If it helps, this gets highlighted when the app crashes:

```
0x2281b61:  calll  0x2281b66       CA::Layer::ensure_transaction_recursively(CA::Transaction*) + 14
```

Comment: what is container view? scrollView?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make like this:

```
-(IBAction)createContainer:(id)sender {
    [allScrollViews addObject:self.containerView];
    for (int i = 0; i < allScrollViews.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame = self.containerView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.containerView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        self.containerView.frame = frame;

        [self.scrollView addSubview: self.containerView];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.containerView.frame.size.width * allScrollViews.count, self.containerView.frame.size.height);   

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but pressing the button still crashes.

Comment: I hope you understand idea. It was my goal.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say. However, it is not instantiating anything new, it is just reloading a view that was already there. I was trying to get a "duplicate" of the existing view but in a different page. Thanks anyway, I'll still fiddle with it.